# Integral over the range of a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute the analytical solution an integral

$$ \int_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})} f(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$

where $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})$ stands for the range of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. I know how to do that for special cases (e.g., line embedded in 2d, surface in 3d).

$f$ is a scalar function of vector $\mathbf{x}$. I am interested in the general case, but as a concrete example, let's say that

$$f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\exp(\mu_i-\alpha_i^\intercal \mathbf{x})}{\big(1 + \exp(\mu_i-\alpha_i^\intercal \mathbf{x})\big)^2}$$

where $\mathbf{A}=[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\ldots,\alpha_N]$.

How can I do that in general? I have a metric ton of such functions and would like to automate it...

Comment: what mean : solve an integral ?

Comment: solve = compute the analytical solution

Comment: Is $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$? In this case, $f({\bf x})d{\bf x}$ is a scalar product? If $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$, then your integral correspond to $m$ integrals, i.e. $\int f({\bf x}) dx_1$, $\int f({\bf x}) dx_2$, and so on.

Comment: Please, give an example of such a function $f$ and explain where you are stucked.

Comment: I have added an example!